# Convert an adjacency list to an ltree in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, tree

I have a tree structure stored as an adjacency list in PostgreSQL 9.6:

"departments" table (parent_id = -1 means a node has no parent)

```
   id   |   name   |   parent_id
-----------------------------------
-1      | NULL     | -1
 1      | Dep_1    | -1
 2      | Dep_2    |  1
 3      | Dep_3    |  1
 4      | Dep_4    |  3
 5      | Dep_5    | -1
```

I need to convert it to `ltree` type with id's as path labels:

```
   id   |   name   |   path
------------------------------
1       | Dep_1    | 1
2       | Dep_2    | 1.2
3       | Dep_3    | 1.3
4       | Dep_4    | 1.3.4
5       | Dep_5    | 5
```

What's the easiest way to do this? Is it possible using SQL only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say I create a table a and fill it with your data, then recursive CTE will do it neat:

```
t=# with recursive r(id, name, path) as (
    select id, name, ''::text
    from a
    where id = -1
union all
    select o.id, o.name, concat(path, '.', o.id)
    from a o
    join r n on o.parent_id = n.id and o.id <> -1
)
select id,name,right(path,-1)::ltree path
from r
where id <> -1
order by id asc;
 id |    name    | path
----+------------+-------
  1 |  Dep_1     | 1
  2 |  Dep_2     | 1.2
  3 |  Dep_3     | 1.3
  4 |  Dep_4     | 1.3.4
  5 |  Dep_5     | 5
(5 rows)
```